# Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value

Tags: html, angular

In Angular 1 I could select the default option for a drop down box using the following:

```
<select 
    data-ng-model="carSelection"
    data-ng-options = "x.make for x in cars" data-ng-selected="$first">
</select>
```

In Angular 2 I have:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```

How could I select a default option given my option data is:

`[{name: 'arm'}, {name: 'back'}, {name:'leg'}]` and my value I to default on on is `back`?

Answer (score 89):

Add a binding to the `selected` property, like this:

```
<option *ngFor="#workout of workouts" 
    [selected]="workout.name == 'back'">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, looking at my selected option it does not have any sort of selected indication

Comment: @ClickThisNick It worked when I tested it. See [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vBqCr05sSeL3FWO8SJ1z?p=preview). When it finishes loading, the select dropdown shows "two" even though the normal default would be the first element ("one").

Comment: The difference with the code in the @Douglas plnr is that is does not have a `[(ngModel)]` binding therefore it listens to the `[selected]` binding in the plnkr and not in the OP's coden (see my answer for a link to a forked plnr that explains this effect)

Comment: Dynamic Forms use: `selected="workout.name == 'back'"` Reactive Forms use: `[selected]=workout.name == 'back'`

Comment: @fidev, you have a great answer, and it was exactly what I was looking for. Just have a look that your Reactive forms example are missing the `"`. I used your code with another variable like this `[selected]="workout.name == exercise.name"`

Answer (score 52):

If you assign the default value to `selectedWorkout` and use `[ngValue]` (which allows to use objects as value - otherwise only string is supported) then it should just do what you want:

```ts
<select class="form-control" name="sel" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" 
    (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let workout of workouts" [ngValue]="workout">
    {{workout.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Ensure that the value you assign to `selectedWorkout` is the same instance than the one used in `workouts`. Another object instance even with the same properties and values won't be recognized. Only object identity is checked.

**update**

Angular added support for `compareWith`, that makes it easier to set the default value when `[ngValue]` is used (for object values)

From the docs https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

> ```ts
> <select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries">
>     <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
>         {{country.name}}
>     </option>
> </select>
> ```

> ```ts
> compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
>     return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
> }
> ```

This way a different (new) object instance can be set as default value and `compareFn` is used to figure out if they should be considered equal (for example if the `id` property is the same.

Comment: if you have time, could you make a plunkr for this? For some reason when I try it $event is coming across as an event and not the object. If I change event to event.target.value, the value comes across as a string like '[object]'

Comment: I guess it would be more helpful if you try to create a Plunker that allows to reproduce your issue ;-) Perhaps you are using `[value]` instead of `[ngValue]` or your code somehow causes the value to be converted to a string.

Comment: What do `c1` and `c2` indicate in `compareFn`? And also, how does the evaluation in the function body work?

Comment: The value `selectedCountries` and `country`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why is `c1 && c2` necessary?

Comment: Necessary for what? If you want to use `compareWith`, then they are necessary

Comment: I'm asking about the syntax: `c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2`
Why do I need to check c1 && c2 beforehand? I thought it should just work with `c1.id === c2.id`.

Comment: What if ’c1` or `c2` is `null` you'd get an exception

Comment: You're right. What I don't understand about the behaviour of `compareFn` is that when I run it, c2, which is `selectedCountries`, stays null till the end of `*ngFor` and after that `compareFn` re-runs with a value assigned(selectedCountries) in `c2`.

Comment: I don't know about that

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have added a question in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689727/angular-select-default-value-shows-empty

Comment: I got it working thanks to the first part of this answer.

Answer (score 38):

Add this Code at o position of the select list.

`<option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Select</option>`

Comment: what is the purpose to setting [ngValue] to undefined?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Setting [ngValue] to undefined properly handles having a default value selected when the 'select' first renders.

Comment: Agreed this is the correct answer.  Allows you to use option at position 0

Comment: @bluePearl the model 'SelectedWorkout' start as 'undefined'  if you don't set to it nothing.Then that's need to be de value of the default item.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 36):

just set the value of the model to the default you want like this:

```
selectedWorkout = 'back'
```

I created a fork of @Douglas' plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gmcHr2GLom4ibZf4pWDw) to demonstrate the various ways to get the desired behavior in angular2.

Comment: for this to work for me(in angular 4) I also had to set [ngValue]="val". My itemssource was not an array of objects though but just an array of strings. `<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTimeFrame">
            <option *ngFor="let val of timeFrames" [ngValue]="val">val</option>
        </select>`

Answer (score 21):

You Can approach this way:

```
<option *ngFor="let workout of workouts" [value]="workout.name">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

or this way:

```
  <option *ngFor="let workout of workouts" [attr.value]="workout.name" [attr.selected]="workout.name == 'leg' ? true : null">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

or you can set default value this way:

```
<option [value]="null">Please Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let workout of workouts" [value]="workout.name">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

or

```
<option [value]="0">Please Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let workout of workouts" [value]="workout.name">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

Comment: The first option works in my case, I did not check the rest. Thank you :)

Answer (score 14):

Use index to show the first value as default

```
<option *ngFor="let workout of workouts; #i = index" [selected]="i == 0">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor you
just need the following:

theView.html:

```
<select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

theComponent.ts

```
import { SelectControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
    compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Struggled a bit with this one, but ended up with the following solution... maybe it will help someone.

HTML template:

```
<select (change)="onValueChanged($event.target)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of uifOptions" [value]="option.value" [selected]="option == uifSelected ? true : false">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';    
export class UifDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() uifOptions: {value: string, text: string}[];
    @Input() uifSelectedValue: string = '';
    @Output() uifSelectedValueChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    uifSelected: {value: string, text: string} = {'value':'', 'text':''};

    constructor() { }

    onValueChanged(target: HTMLSelectElement):void {
        this.uifSelectedValue = target.value;
        this.uifSelectedValueChange.emit(this.uifSelectedValue);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uifSelected = this.uifOptions.filter(o => o.value == 
        this.uifSelectedValue)[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fully fleshing out other posts, here is what works in Angular2 quickstart,

To set the DOM default: along with `*ngFor`, use a conditional statement in the `<option>`'s `selected` attribute.

To set the `Control`'s default: use its constructor argument. Otherwise before an onchange when the user re-selects an option, which sets the control's value with the selected option's value attribute, the control value will be null.

script:

```
import {ControlGroup,Control} from '@angular/common';
...
export class MyComponent{
  myForm: ControlGroup;
  myArray: Array<Object> = [obj1,obj2,obj3];
  myDefault: Object = myArray[1]; //or obj2

  ngOnInit(){ //override
    this.myForm = new ControlGroup({'myDropdown': new Control(this.myDefault)});
  }
  myOnSubmit(){
    console.log(this.myForm.value.myDropdown); //returns the control's value 
  }
}
```

markup:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myOnSubmit()">
  <select ngControl="myDropdown">
    <option *ngFor="let eachObj of myArray" selected="eachObj==={{myDefault}}"
            value="{{eachObj}}">{{eachObj.myText}}</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Use that `[ngModel]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`and it is Ok

```
<select class="form-control" **[ngModel]="selectedWorkout"** (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
   <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as above:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" 
        (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts;
                    let itemIndex = index"
            [attr.selected]="itemIndex == 0">
    {{workout.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In above code as you can see, selected attribute of the repeating option is set on checking index of the repeating loop of list. [attr.< html attribute name >] is used for setting html attribute in angular2.

Another approach will be setting model value in typescript file as :

```
this.selectedWorkout = this.workouts.length > 0
                       ? this.workouts[0].name
                       : 'No data found';//'arm'
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem while using angular 11. But finally found a solution.

```html
  <option disabled selected value="undefined">Select an Option</option>
```

complete example with ngFor.

```html
<select name="types" id="types" [(ngModel)]="model.type" #type="ngModel">
  <option class="" disabled selected value="undefined">Select an Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of course_types; let x = index" [ngValue]="type.id">
    {{ item.name }} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add on to @Matthijs 's answer, please make sure your `select` element has a `name` attribute and its `name` is unique in your html template. Angular 2 is using input name to update changes. Thus, if there are duplicated names or there is no name attached to input element, the binding will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Add binding property selected, but make sure to make it null, for other fields e.g:

```
<option *ngFor="#workout of workouts" [selected]="workout.name =='back' ? true: null">{{workout.name}}</option>
```

Now it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" name='someting' [ngModel]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
    <option value="{{workout.name}}" *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```

If you are using form there should be `name` field inside `select` tag.

All you need to do is just add `value` to the `option` tag.

`selectedWorkout` value should be "back" , and its done.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the 2-way binding via [(ngModel)], do this:

```
<select (change)="selectedAccountName = $event.target.value">
  <option *ngFor="let acct of accountsList" [ngValue]="acct">{{ acct.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Just tested on my project on Angular 4 and it works! The accountsList is an array of Account objects in which name is a property of Account.

Interesting observation:
[ngValue]="acct" exerts the same result as [ngValue]="acct.name".
Don't know how Angular 4 accomplish it!

Answer (score 0):

> **Step: 1 Create Properties declare class**

```
export class Task {
    title: string;
    priority: Array<any>;
    comment: string;

    constructor() {
        this.title      = '';
        this.priority   = [];
        this.comment    = '';
     }
}
```

> **Stem: 2 Your Component Class**

```
import { Task } from './task';

export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
  priorityList: Array<any> = [
    { value: 0, label: '✪' },
    { value: 1, label: '★' },
    { value: 2, label: '★★' },
    { value: 3, label: '★★★' },
    { value: 4, label: '★★★★' },
    { value: 5, label: '★★★★★' }
  ];
  taskModel: Task           = new Task();

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskModel.priority     = [3]; // index number
  }
}
```

> **Step: 3 View File .html**

```
<select class="form-control" name="priority" [(ngModel)]="taskModel.priority"  required>
    <option *ngFor="let list of priorityList" [value]="list.value">
      {{list.label}}
    </option>
</select>
```

> **Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the ngModel and the value you want selected:

```
<select id="typeUser" ngModel="Advanced" name="typeUser">
  <option>Basic</option>
  <option>Advanced</option>
  <option>Pro</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I define some properties:

```
disabledFirstOption = true;

get isIEOrEdge(): boolean {
    return /msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
}
```

Then in the constructor and ngOnInit

```
constructor() {
    this.disabledFirstOption = false;
}

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.disabledFirstOption = true;
    });
}
```

And in the template I add this as the first option inside the select element

```
<option *ngIf="isIEOrEdge" [value]="undefined" [disabled]="disabledFirstOption" selected></option>
```

If you allow to select the first option you can just remove the usage of the property disabledFirstOption

Answer (score 0):

In my case, here `this.selectedtestSubmitResultView` is set with default value based on conditions and an variable `testSubmitResultView` must be one and same as `testSubmitResultView`. This indeed worked for me

```
<select class="form-control" name="testSubmitResultView"  [(ngModel)]="selectedtestSubmitResultView" (ngModelChange)="updatetestSubmitResultView($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let testSubmitResultView of testSubmitResultViewArry" [ngValue]="testSubmitResultView" >
        {{testSubmitResultView.testSubmitResultViewName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

For More Information,

```
testSubmitResultViewArry: Array<any> = [];
selectedtestSubmitResultView: string;
    
getTestSubmitResultViewList() {
    try {
        this.examService.getTestSubmitResultViewDetails().subscribe(response => {
            if (response != null && response !== undefined && response.length > 0) {
                response.forEach(x => {
                    if (x.isDeleted === false) {
                        this.testSubmitResultViewArry.push(x);
                    }
                    if (x.isDefault === true) {
                        this.selectedtestSubmitResultView = x;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('Method: getTestSubmitResultViewList' + ex.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this Issue before and I fixed it with vary simple workaround way

For your Component.html

```
      <select class="form-control" ngValue="op1" (change)="gotit($event.target.value)">

      <option *ngFor="let workout of workouts" value="{{workout.name}}" name="op1" >{{workout.name}}</option>

     </select>
```

Then in your component.ts you can detect the selected option by

```
gotit(name:string) {
//Use it from hare 
console.log(name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

works great as seen below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTipoDocumento" formControlName="tipoDocumento" [compareWith]="equals"
          [class.is-valid]="this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid &&
           (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)"
          [class.is-invalid]="!this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid &&
           (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)">
            <option value="">Selecione um tipo</option>
            <option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposDocumento" [ngValue]="tipo">{{tipo?.nome}}</option>
          </select>
```