# Angular 2, set default value to select option

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I try to add a default value to an option. It will be like a kind of placeholder and I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box) to do it.
In pure HTML it work, but if I try to use `*ngFor` of angular 2 attribute, it doesn't select anything.

Here my code that I use in pure HTML:

```
  <select name="select-html" id="select-html">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Language</option>
    <option value="1">HTML</option>
    <option value="2">PHP</option>
    <option value="3">Javascript</option>
  </select>
```

And using Angular template:

```
 <select name="select" id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectLanguage">
    <option *ngFor="let item of selectOption" 
      [selected]="item.value==0" 
      [disabled]="item.value==0">{{item.label}}</option>
  </select>
```

The class is

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-form-select',
  templateUrl: 'default.component.html'
})
export class DefaultComponent {
  private selectOption: any;
  constructor() {
    this.selectOption = [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: "Select Language",
        value: 0
      }, {
        id: 2,
        label: "HTML 5",
        value: 1
      }, {
        id: 3,
        label: "PHP",
        value: 2
      }, {
        id: 4,
        label: "Javascript",
        value: 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want `Select Language`to be selected as a default value. It's disabled but not selected.

How can I select it as a default value?

**[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuMlp7XE8tDlDYLoOfni?p=preview)**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**update**

[4.0.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/4.0.0-beta.5...4.0.0-beta.6) added `compareWith`

```
<select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>

compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
   return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

this way the instance assigned to `selectedCountries` doesn't need to be the identical object, but a custom comparison function can be passed, for example to be able to match an different object instance with identical property values.

**original**

If you want to use an object as value you need to use `[ngValue]` on the option element.

```
  <select name="select" id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectLanguage">
    <option *ngFor="let item of selectOption" [ngValue]="item"
      [disabled]="item.value==0">{{item.label}}</option>
  </select>
```

When `selectLanguage` has an options value assigned `[(ngModel)]="..."` will this one make the one selected by default:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-form-select',
  templateUrl: 'default.component.html'
})
export class DefaultComponent {
  private selectOption: any;
  constructor() {
    this.selectOption = [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: "Select Language",
        value: 0
      }, {
        id: 2,
        label: "HTML 5",
        value: 1
      }, {
        id: 3,
        label: "PHP",
        value: 2
      }, {
        id: 4,
        label: "Javascript",
        value: 3
      }
    ];
    this.selectLanguage = this.selectOption[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: @CTN sorry, I don't understand your question. What label and what HTML DOM?

Comment: I want to set html tag to label value.

Comment: if you are looking for Angular 11 solution. Answer is here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66229168/9207553

Comment: Thanks for the `compareWith` solution! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 21):

I find it nicer to remove the default option from the `selectOption` array and specifying the default unselectable option separately.

```
<select name="select" id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectLanguage">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled>Select Language</option>
  <option
         *ngFor="let item of selectOption"
         [value]="item.value"
  >
    item.label
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer.  The other answer is super convoluted.

Comment: This is the absolute answer I was looking for. This is useful when you want to select default options like "Select blah blah" when your options come from a service dynamically.

Answer (score 8):

Try below sample code for this:
Replace `yourValue` with whatever value you want to select default

```
<select  placeholder="country" >
       <option *ngFor="let country of countriesList" [ngValue]="country" [selected]="country.country_name == yourValue" >
             {{country.country_name}}
       </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="someList.key" name="key"  #key="ngModel" required>
     <option value="undefined" selected disabled>Select option</option>
     <option *ngFor="let data of someList" value="{{data.key}}">{{data.key}</option>
 </select>
```