# Reactive form validation treats default 'select' value of select input box as valid

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have been struggling to validate a Reactive form with default "select" option to my select input box when there's no value selected. If a value is present in the form then I need to select the respective value.

I am using reactive form and below is my code implementation:

```html
<select class="form-control" formControlName="environment" >
    <option disabled [value]="null">-- Select --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let ami of envs" [value]="ami.amiid">
        {{ami.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

```ts
this.onlineTestForm = this._fb.group({
            .
            .    
            environment: ['', Validators.required],
            .
            .         
        });

//value is present in the model
(<FormControl>this.onlineTestForm.controls['environment'])
           .setValue(this.model.environment, { onlySelf: true });

//value is not present in model
(<FormControl>this.onlineTestForm.controls['environment'])
           .setValue('null', { onlySelf: true });
```

Is there a better way to achieve the above?

Comment: maybe this will help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724161/angular-2-set-default-value-to-select-option?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```ts
(<FormControl>this.onlineTestForm.controls['environment'])
       .setValue('null', { onlySelf: true });
```

you are setting **string** value `'null'` instead of `null`. The string `'null'` is of course a valid value.

Also you are setting a complete object as the value of the form control if it exists, even though `environment` expects just the id, at least what you have specified in the template:

```html
[value]="ami.amiid"
```

---

I see two options here to "improve" your code. These depend on if `this.model` gets the values asynchronously or not. If you know the value of `this.model` on initialization, you can simply do this:

```ts
environment: [this.model.environment || null, 
              Validators.required]
```

Here we must remember to initialize `model` as an empty object, so that an `undefined` error will not be thrown in case there is no value in `model`.

---

If `model` value is set asynchronously, use `setValue` to set the value once you get it:

```ts
this.onlineTestForm.controls.environment.setValue(...)
```