# Select in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have in my view:

```
<select id="field_cliente" name="cliente"
        [(ngModel)]="oportunidad.cliente">
       <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
       <option [ngValue]="clienteOption" *ngFor="let clienteOption of clientes; trackBy: trackClienteById">{{clienteOption.razonSocial}}</option>
</select>
```

I have in my controller:

```
trackClienteById(index: number, item: Cliente) {
    return item;
}
```

The object is:

```
cliente{
       id:"",
       razonSocial:""
}
```

The value loads well when I select one, but when entering if it already has a previous value, it does not fit the value with the "select" and the "select" goes empty, even if the entity has value.

Comment: How to you declare Cliente class ? I set up a demo, you can correct to your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kr2ten?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end I was given an example by a friend. It's a great help for the link you sent me to try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2, set default value to select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724161/angular-2-set-default-value-to-select-option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select  [compareWith]="equals" ...
```

in controller:

```
equals(o1: Cliente, o2: Cliente) { return o1.id === o2.id; }
```