# Drop-down List Default value not showing Angular-6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

Am trying  to bind an array into a list .binding part is working fine.but the default value of drop down is not showing. Initially array doesn't have any value.

code

```
<select (change)="select($event)" [(ngModel)]="drp_selectedValue" >
                    <option value ="">Select.....</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let list of dataList?.length > 0 " (click)="select(list)" [ngValue]="list">{{list.name}}</option>

                </select>
```

currently my list showing like this

[image]

Am also tried to check dataList length and put value="" ,but not working.what was wrong in my code?

Comment: Just initialize `drp_selectedValue` with `''`

Comment: thanks @xyz. Its working fine

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343415/angular-2-how-to-set-select-default-selected-option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially set drp_selectedValue as ''

`drp_selectedValue = '';`