# Set default value for dropdown angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried some of the resources here but never worked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value). I want to set default value to the dropdown from the component. I have tried using Ngmodel to Select element and Selected attribute to the option element but doesn't seem to work

**template**

```
<li *ngFor="let seats of quantityForView">
    <select (change)="ChangeTicketQuantity($event)" id="selectQuantityChange" [(ngModel)] ="seats.seatQuantitySelected">
        <option *ngFor="let ticketQuantity of seats.quantityList" [value]="ticketQuantity">
            {{ticketQuantity}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

**Component**

```
export class ChangeSeatQuantity  {
cartLineItems: any;
maxSeats: number;
selectedSeatQuantity: number;
quantityForView: any;

constructor(private _store: Store<any>) {
    this.cartLineItems = (<any>window).bootstrap.promoBoxViewModel.currentCart.cartLineItems;
    this.selectedSeatQuantity = this.cartLineItems[0].quantity;
    this.maxSeats = 10;
    this.SetQuantityForView();
}

SetQuantityForView()
{
    this.quantityForView = this.cartLineItems.map((seatsAvailable: any) => ({
        quantityList: Array(10).fill(1,1).map((x, i) => i),
        selectedSeatQuantity: this.cartLineItems[0].quantity
    }));
}
}
```

**Data**

```
this.quantityForView
[Object]
    0: Object
      quantityList: Array(10)
          1: 1
          2: 2
          3: 3
          4: 4
          5: 5
          6: 6
          7: 7
          8: 8
          9: 9
      length: 10
      __proto__: Array(0)
     selectedSeatQuantity: 2
     __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: @MBielski I have added a sample data that's sent to the dropdown

Comment: @MBielski any idea?

Comment: sorry, but no. Seems like it should work to me.

Comment: What is this `cartLineItems`?

Comment: I don't see seats in your Component code. Is it just missing?