# Dropdowns onChange

Tags: angular

I've been reading and found that there are lots of variations to this question, but I have not yet found one that worked. This is my HTML:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDepartment" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let department of Directory.categories" [ngValue]="department.id">{{department.option}}</option>
</select>
```

My department.option list includes: 'All Departments', 'Department One', and 'Department Two'. Right now, the dropdown starts with a blank selection, and you can only see the options if you click the dropdown arrow. So, the dropdown really acts like: blank, 'All Departments', 'Department One', etc. I want it to use 'All Departments' as a default. 
I've tried just about every solution I've found here, but have yet to figure out something that actually works.
Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value) question is very similar to mine, none of the solutions on that page worked for my project.

**UPDATE: (the solution)**

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDepartment" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let department of Directory.categories" [ngValue]="department">{{department.option}}</option>
</select>

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedDepartment = this.Directory.categories[0];
}
```

**BUT**
Now, my `onChange($event)` is passing an object to the `onChange` function, so my pipe filter isn't working correctly. This was fixed by using `[ngValue]="department.id"` and `this.Directory.categories[0].id;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value)

Comment: You can just do in your component: `this.selectedDepartment = this.Directory.categories[0];`

Comment: Yup, like @devqon said. also you need to remove `.id` from your `ngValue`. I assume you want to bind the whole object? Then use `[ngValue]="department"` and `this.selectedDepartment = this.Directory.categories[0];`  If not, then use `[value]="department.id"` and then you need to set `this.selectedDepartment = this.Directory.categories[0].id`, demo with `ngValue`: http://plnkr.co/edit/iEf4SwO1RG0Jp3Jylhr0?p=preview

Comment: @AJT_82 thank you!!! I got it working using **[ngValue] = "department"** and then following your plnkr link to figure out where to put the **this** statement.

Comment: @a_lovelace You are very welcome! :)

Comment: Yes look at the comment, you perhaps only want to use value? Here it passes just the id: http://plnkr.co/edit/XAcYHBamriWo0brqh12Z?p=preview

Comment: @a_lovelace I see you updated, if you just want to pass a primitive type, in this case a number, use just `[value]="department.id"`. it will work with `[ngValue]`, as you noticed, but that is actually meant to bind an object. Just a detail ;) Have a gooood day and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two-way data binding like `[(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment`", you can also set this in the component ts file

`selectedDepartment = 1;`

and it will default to that value

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDepartment" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let department of Directory.categories; let i = index" [ngValue]="department.id" [selected]="i === 0 ? 'true' : 'false'">{{department.option}}</option>
</select>
```

Basically, you say that if it's the first option, you set its property to selected.

Comment: Your solution makes sense and in theory should work beautifully, but it's still leaving the pre-set value of the dropdown blank...

Comment: Then try setting your `selectedDepartment` to `Directory.categories[0].id` in your `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

I have included the dropdown with values

```js
  On your ts file 
  
      directory:any; 
    this.Directory = [{option: '--sel--', value: 0}];
```

```html
<select class="selectedDepartment"[(ngModel)]="electrify" (ngModelChange)="electrifyonChange($event)">
               <option *ngFor="let let department of Directory.categories" [ngvalue]="department.id">{{department.option}} </option>
          </select>
```