# How to get Select box click event in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I would like to get Select box click event in angular2.
I don't want to get change event.

Ex:- Select box has two options(Male and Female), first i select male.
Next time also i will select male only in this case changEvent will not help us.

Here i would like to get only selectEvent irrespective of the value change.

Comment: make use of ngmodel

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the initial value to male in your component?

Example:

public gender: string = 'male';

Also see here:

[Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value)

Comment: My Query is not about setting the value. what i am looking is to get slick event of an option.