# Angular 2 change option in select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have 2 selects:

```
 <form name="newDocumentForm">
<label for="companySelect"> Company: </label>
<select name="companySelect" id="companySelect" [(ngModel)]="companySelect" 
 (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Select...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company">{{company.name}}</option>
</select>

<label for="documentTypeSelect"> Type: </label>
<select name="documentTypeSelect" id="documentTypeSelect" 
 [(ngModel)]="documentTypeSelect">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Select...</option>
  <option value="aaa">ty</option>
  <option value="bbbb">ew</option>
</select>
</form>
```

What should i add to onChange($event) to set the documentTypeSelect option to "Select..." everytime i change something in the first select?
Something like this.documentTypeSelect = ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<option [ngValue]="undefined"
```

to

```
<option [ngValue]="''"
```

If you then set `companySelect` to `''` this option will be selected

```
companySelect:string = '';
```

For more complicated scenarios, see also [Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value/37477363#37477363)