# Angular 5 dropdown setting default value

Tags: angular5, dropdown

I am trying to preselect (set as default)  value from Angular 5 drop down.

There are three values and I am trying to set the second one with this code but it doesn't work. I can't make any changes in the component, only in the template.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="declaration.media" name="media" (change)="onChangeMedia()" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
    <option *ngFor="let media of mediaArray" value="{{media.value}}" selected = "{{media.value == '02'}}">{{media.text}}</option>
</select>
```

UPDATE: if I remove [(ngModel)] then it works, but no two way binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please add any description how this fragment of plain HTML code can help to solve the OP's problem with setting of default select value in Angular 5?