# Angular - Setting default value for dropdown - solutions not working?

Tags: angular, typescript

**Goal**: Set default value for a dropdown that changes the address of the site the user is on /en/ or /es/ for English or Spanish

**Problem**: After going through documentation and through every SO article I could find such as [Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value), none of the variations seem to work.

What is wrong?
And do I need a form/mat-form or is there a simpler way to do this?

**What I've tried**: Here are some of the variations of what I've tried in the HTML and in the TypeScript:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [value]="language"> 
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [value]="English">  
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [(ngModel)]='defaultLanguage'>
```

**HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="_siteForm">
      <mat-form-field class="right">
          <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [(ngModel)]='defaultLanguage'>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
                  {{language.viewValue}}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**:

```
public _siteForm             : FormGroup;
this._siteForm = fb.group({
            'languages' : ['']
        });
public languages = [
  { value: "en", viewValue: 'English' },
  { value: "es", viewValue: 'Spanish' }
   ];

public defaultLanguage          : string = "English";

if (this.localeId == "en") { this._siteForm.controls["languages"].setValue(this.languages.filter(item => item.value === 'en')[0].viewValue); }
else { this._siteForm.controls["languages"].setValue(this.languages.filter(item => item.value === 'es')[0].viewValue); }
```

Alternate

```
this._siteForm.setValue({ languages: "en" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason could be the type of values you are setting as default and the type of objects you are looping through.

The type is `string` here:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [value]="language"> 
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [value]="English">
```

But it's JSON object here:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
     {{language.viewValue}}
</mat-option>
```

Make both the same type, both JSON objects or both strings.

If you use `[value]="languages[0]"` it would set default value using the first element of the languages array.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7771#issuecomment-336482394

Comment: .the mat-option has value=language and also the mat-select. Are you saying value is string for mat-option? I've used this format in other areas without problem. Why is it not working here?

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the setValue method have changed that though? How would I set it to JSON? The syntax in your comment looks identical.

Comment: I tried patchValue as well but that did not work. Adding {{language.viewValue}} to the mat-select brakes the page.

Comment: @angleUr @angleUr Do this to mat-select: `[value]="languages[0]"`

Comment: I did this with languages[i] so it could be dynamic, and it worked.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include what you have in the comment? As is, it doesnt work, but your comment worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public languages = [
  { value: "en", viewValue: 'English' },
  { value: "es", viewValue: 'Spanish' }
   ];

public defaultLanguage = languages[0]; // or languages[1]
```

What I noticed right away is your are trying to make your ngModel, which is a **string** match your [value] which is an **object**

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [(ngModel)]='defaultLanguage'>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
          {{language.viewValue}}
     </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like this:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">
    {{language.viewValue}}
</mat-option>
```

Then set the default language to one of those values:

```
public defaultLanguage: String = "en";
```

This way the options are simple strings rather than JSON making them easily comparable. Currently your defaultLanguage variable doesn't match either of the options.